# How to I build gnu-efi, for mingw-w64

Tags: mingw-w64, msys2, gnu-efi

I am new to the gnu-efi development process. I am using windows 11, and GCC 13.1.0 (with POSIX threads) + LLVM/Clang/LLD/LLDB 16.0.5 + MinGW-w64 11.0.0 (UCRT) - release 5 (Latest), Win64. So far I have managed to install the zip, and install make for the msys2 mingw-w64 terminal. I am now trying to build the files with the makefile in the root directory. It is able to compile most of the files, but when it reaches the ctors.S, it generate the following errors.

```
C:/Users/[my username]/gnu-efi/lib/ctors.S:11: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
C:/Users/[my username]/gnu-efi/lib/ctors.S:18: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
C:/Users/[my username]/gnu-efi/lib/ctors.S:25: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
C:/Users/[my username]/gnu-efi/lib/ctors.S:32: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
```

Why does it do this. I have tried changing the section names for the first line, and used sasm to test the assembly process. I have tried looking at the documentation for gas and changing the syntax to that, yet it still generated the error. Can someone guide me as to why this is happening, and how to fix this error? Thank you.
Note: I am using the mingw-w64 version of the as.

Thank you to Hossien Tahazid for helping the edit. My bad.

Update: I have tried using the mingw-w64 compiler on linux. It did not work. However, when I used the native linux compiler, the assembler worked completely. No errors generated.

Thank you to ssbssa for linking me to that bug. IS there a way for me to build edk2 on windows for mingw-w64, that way I can use visual studio code, is there a way to build it on Linux, convert the files to mingw-w64 suitable files, and then use those, or is there some other solution?

Update: I tried linking against only a part of the library, and it did not work. I've decided to stop trying to build gnu-efi for mingw-w64 until something is found, and shut up and use linux.

Comment: Looks like [this bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnu-efi/bugs/38/).